# Improving performance of keyset pagination after filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I have a table like this:

```
Post:
    id int
    time int
    title varchar(100)
```

I want to filter the table based on the title and then paginate the result. For pagination, I'm using keyset pagination using `where time < last_post_time or (time = last_post_time and id > last_post_id)`. I have 2 indexes on the table, one for searching and another for pagination:

- index on (title)
- index on (time desc, id)

SQL for the table:

```
create table test ( 
    id int, 
    time int, 
    title varchar(100), 
    primary key (id) , 
    index idx_title (title), 
    index idx_time_id (time desc, id) 
);
```

SQL Query:

```
explain select id, time, title 
from test
where title = 'some title'
and time < 10 or (time = 10 and id > 5)
order by time desc, id, title
limit 10
```

The output says it is using idx_time_id, which makes sense. I'm assuming it would first filter based on the time and id, and then do a whole scan on the filtered data for the title (since index for title can't be used since its already filtered)

Is there a way to have it avoid doing a scan on the entire filtered data? Because its possible that time and id condition results in the whole table being returned, which would mean it would search through the whole table for finding the titles..

How do I optimize this query for filtering and then doing pagination on it?

Comment: but your query ask also for title and mysqö only usrs one index, which it sees fit, you can force an index so add a index idx_time_time_id (time desc,title,  id) and play with the order a bit, then run test with some 100000 entries and test all indexes you have

Comment: Unless you have a whole lot of entries with the same title (which of course can be the case for your data), it would not expect you to need an on time. The query you are using seems to be missing a bracket though, e.g. it should (probably) be `where title = 'some title' and (time < 10 or (time = 10 and id > 5))`. Also note that performance measurements on very small sample test tables do not necessarily have anything to do with the performance when the table gets filled.

Comment: Check the "<" and ">" in your query -- shouldn't they be the same direction??

Comment: @RickJames time is desc and id is asc which is why its different.

Comment: @wingerse - Strange -- Most users want the "latest", which would be `ORDER BY time DESC, id DESC`.  And `title` would not be in the `ORDER BY` because id is unique.

Comment: @RickJames that makes more sense. Idk why I was doing id asc, and for title, that's definitely a good point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the query is really more like this:

```
select  id, time, title
    from  test
    where  title = 'some title'
      and  time < 10
      or  (time = 10
              and  id < 5    -- getting older
          )
    order by  time desc, id DESC  -- both DESC, no need for `title`
    limit  10
```

The table needs `INDEX(title, time, id)` in this order.  And you may as well drop `INDEX(title)`.

This allows you to "remember where you left off" and continue with a new `LIMIT 10` without out `OFFEST`.  (More discussion:  [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) )